# Use Serverless or Zappa without Iam GetRole authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, zappa

I am using AWS Educate Starter account but their user account policy don't allow to have Iam GetRole. So I am having this kind off errors in both Serverless framework and Zappa -

```
An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - API: iam:GetRole 
User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/awsstudent is not authorized to perform: 
iam:GetRole on resource: role hello-world-dev-us-west-2-lambdaRole.
```

Is there any way to get the job done without this authorization. I know that my access key has the full access to AWS lamda, S3, Api Gateway etc.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you seem to be locked out of IAM. No amount of permission on Lambda/S3/API Gateway is going to get you to where you need to go.